# Pass Data from ViewController to ChildContainerContainer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I am using Swift. I have 2 ViewControllers a) ParentVC & b) ChildVC. When I instantiate the chidVC, I want to pass some data from Parent to Child. Not sure how. Below is the code

**ParentVC**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChildViewController") as UIViewController!

    //I want to pass some value - For example: controller.id = 3

    addChildViewController(controller)
    containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
    didMoveToParentViewController(controller)      
}
```

**Within Child VC**

```
 var id: Int?
```

P.S: I definitely want to use "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier". I have seen [Passing Data Between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers), but thats in ObjC and I am looking for code in Swift as I don't know how to translate it. Also I don't want to use prepareForSegue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Its not a duplicate..that entire answer is in ObjC. I am looking for Swift version as I don't know how to translate it. You should atleast read the question (i specifically mentioned Swift in the title) before downvoting

Comment: Did you even read that? The link contains answer in Swift as well.

Comment: Yes I did..the only swift explaination is for prepareforsegue method..I know how to do that..I dont know how to pass data between Parent & Child when I instantiate. I am not using prepareforsegue because there is no segue happening. If you know how..atleast type in the code..

Comment: I don't mind you downviting but atleast post a decent answer -- otherwise pls remove the downvote as noone else will also answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.
In the instantiation of your ChildViewController you need cast into the class of your ChildViewController not UIViewController, because UIViewController does not have the property.

so replace

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChildViewController") as UIViewController!
```

by

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChildViewController") as YourChildViewControllerClass!
```

Edit:
Now you can set the property like truongky answered:

```
controller.yourId = 100
```

Comment: hi..just tried this...it gives me a different error in the "controller.yourID" line..it says expression resolves to an unused I-value

Answer (score 3):

- define yourID in child view controller.
- pass the ID after instantiating

  ```
  let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChildViewController") as YourViewController!

  controller.yourID = 100

  presentViewController(controller, animated:true, completion:nil)
  ```

Comment: i tried that..its not working..the error is that UIViewController does not have a member "yourID"...but as I mentioned in the question as well..I have declared the id variable (just as you mentioned as well).

Comment: your ID is your property you define in Child View Controller.
- Open ChildViewController.swift, define 
        var yourID = 0
- Back to parent viewController and pass ID to your child. 
PS: prevent define id in your code.

Comment: I have declared id in Childview controller class..var id :Int?...
in the ParentVC..

let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChildViewController") as UIViewController!
controller.id = 100

i get an error that controller does not have a member "id"

in the above code if I replace "as UIViewContoller!" as Tplet suggested with "as ChildViewController!" then I get error : expression resolves to an unused i-value

really can't figure this out :(

Comment: `let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChildViewController") as UIViewController!` Sorry about my mistake. Change `UIViewController` to `ParentVC`. Hope this help.